# How to change group that will run httpd without breaking virtualhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

If I set the group to www-users in the httpd.conf then my virtualhost sites stop working.

Have chmod ded 776 everything in /var/www/html and chown ed to [my user]:www-users.

First request to localhost works but second fails every time (connection reset). When setting everything back to apache:apache and restarting httpd then it works fine.

httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost marketingretreiver:80
<VirtualHost marketingretreiver:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Symfony/web
    ServerName marketingretreiver
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Install SuExec along with one of the PHP modules such as suphp or similar then you can define specific group and user per virtualhost and even use 770 as chmod. This question is more suitable for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Prix Thank you for your reply, I'll set the user and group back to apache and that be that. Maybe sometimes use virtual host and then only one at the time (counting localhost as one as well).

Comment: You can have as many virtualhost as you want as long as they have the right permission it should work just fine and every system has its own peculiarities.